# .attr 'alt' displaying only the first word

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, alt

I am stuck over a small issue, i'm trying to print the image titles by getting them from the alt tag. This is not working because it is only showing the first word from the alt.

```
$("#galleryThumbs .imageThumb").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        var newImage = $(this).attr('picURL');
        $('#galleryImageLarge').attr('src', newImage);
        $("#galleryThumbs .imageThumb").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var newTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('#galleryTitle').text(newTitle);
    }
});
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 verticalcenter work" id="largeGalleryImage">
    <img src="<?php echo $galleryImages[0]['sizes']['large']; ?>"
        alt="<?php echo $galleryImages[0]['title']; ?>"
        class="img-responsive" id="galleryImageLarge" />
    <p id="galleryTitle"><?php echo $galleryImages[0]['title']; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: type the code in pure html, you can't compile php in snippets.

Comment: you're clicking on `$("#galleryThumbs .imageThumb")`. Does it have the `alt` attribute? Maybe the issue is not about JavaScript https://jsfiddle.net/Lrp9nrgd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape variables passed from PHP to HTML, i.e. try to replace:

```
<?php echo $galleryImages[0]['title']; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($galleryImages[0]['title']); ?>
```

Your `$galleryImages[0]['title']` might have `"` symbol with would be interpreted as the end of attribute value.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: It seems you are right; the alt is not displaying correct. (displays like: <img alt="one" two three">)

But it's still not working the way you explained.

Id did this:
echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars($galleryThumb['sizes']['thumbnail']).'" class="img-responsive imageThumb imageNum'.htmlspecialchars($i).' '.htmlspecialchars($imgClass).'" alt='.htmlspecialchars($galleryThumb['title']).'" picURL="'.$galleryThumb['sizes']['large'].'" /></div>';

Comment: @TjeerdBosma this is probably because you missed double quotes after `alt=`

Comment: @TjeerdBosma if my answer was helpful, can you please mark it as accepted, so that I will get +15 rep? :D

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have quote marks in the $galleryImages[0]['title'] value. So escape it:

```
alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($galleryImages[0]['title']); ?>"
```

(You should do this for the src, class and id attributes, and the content that goes between the

tags, too.)